# What I sure method I used to authenticate in webpy?

Tags: python, security, web.py

Hello I have an application on my localhost, the application is made with webpy, this application is an administration panel, cpanel style, I can only access because it is running on 127.0.0.1

Now I would like to use it on my public server.

But you need a very secure method of authentication with webpy.

Would use 3 friends and I would then be four to eight users.

How to accomplish this? Can you make a certificate-based method?

o could be stored in blowfish passwords?

I think that as few users are is not necessarily a complex database, perhaps sqlite is enough.

Thank you

Comment: Most of the time you store hashed passwords on your server (you can use [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html)) which is quite easy to setup. I recommend to redirect all the requests to the server to https in the configuration file of the server (use nginx or apache). sqlite is enough ;)

Answer (score 0):

- To use SSL: Add the following lines to the the web.py main file.

  `from web.wsgiserver import CherryPyWSGIServer
  CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_certificate = "/path/to/ssl_certificate"              CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_private_key = "/path/to/ssl_private_key"`

  which allows you to use https, it sets SSL support in built-in cherrypy server web.py. Refer [this](http://webpy.org/cookbook/ssl).
- To use SQLite use the [interface](http://webpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/db.html) given by web.py using sqlite3
  library.

  `db = web.database(dbn="sqlite", db="dbname")`
- You can use [basic authentication](http://webpy.org/cookbook/userauthbasic) provided by web.py if needed.
- Either you can directly run your web.py application in the server
  using: (This limits the concurrent requests to 10)

  `python code.py`

  or you can use Fastcgi deployment through lighttpd is what web.py has recommended for production use. Refer [this](http://webpy.org/install).